# How do i catch all mouse clicks / touch events in my WPF application - even when a WebBrowser is in front

Tags: wpf

I have a full screen WPF application where i host a WebBrowser. Both are in full screen (the Web browser is docked fully). In my WPF application i need to know when any user touches the screen (touch screens) or clicks the mouse (same event). I need the mouse event, even if the user clicks inside a link or button in the WebBrowser. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global hooks FTW: http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/